# access PHP variable outside if/else statement

Tags: php

so I have a if else statement where  I currently can print the statement 'conversation between 'user1', 'user2', etc., but do not know how I would get that to print outside of the if/else statement.

I would like to access it outside that section of PHP, in a section that is before where the variable is generated

Here is my PHP

```
<?php print $conversation_members; ?>

<?php
 if (count($rows)) {
     $uids= array();
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
       $uids[] = $row['userid'];
    }
     $last = array_pop($uids);
     $conversation_members = '<p>Conversation between ';
     $conversation_members .= implode(', ', $uids) . ' and ' . $last;
     $conversation_members .= '.</p>';
}
else {
     blah blah irrelevant
}  
?>
```

Sincere thanks for any help! It is greatly appreciated- a

Comment: Assign the string to variable and print it after the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that returns what you need:

```
function getConversationMembers($result)
{
    $uids = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $uids[] = $row['userid'];
    }

    if (count($uids) >= 2) {
        $last = array_pop($uids);
        return sprintf('<p>Conversation between %s and %s.</p>',
            htmlspecialchars(join(',', $uids), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
            htmlspecialchars($last, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
        );
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Then:

```
<?php print getConversationMembers($result1); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Store it in a variable:

```
$output = ''; // Give a default value
if (count($rows)) {
     $uids= array();
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
       $uids[] = $row['userid'];
    }
     $last = array_pop($uids);
     $output = '<p>Conversation between ';
     $output .= implode(', ', $uids) . ' and ' . $last;
     $ouptut .= '.</p>';
}
else {
     blah blah irrelevant
}  
echo $output;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it apply? The default assignment should also be inside `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Just set that text your are printing out to a variable and `.=` it to the rest of what is being printed out. Then you can use it as a variable anywhere else in you script.

$thisVar = '';

then inside your if else:

$thisVar .= "Conversation blah blah ";

$thisVar .= "four 4";

echo $thisVar;
// will print "Conversation blah blah four 4"

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '';
if (count($rows)) {
         $uids= array();
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
             $uids[] = $row['userid'];
        }
         $last = array_pop($uids);
         $str .= '<p>Conversation between ';
         $str .= implode(', ', $uids) . ' and ' . $last;
         $str .= '.</p>';

         echo $str;
}
else {
        echo $str;
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for the response. What if I was trying to access in a separate bit of php? I will edit my question to reflect this...

Comment: if the variable is getting defined below where you are trying to access it it will not work.  for more flexibility create functions and call that function as you need.